# Saving MJPEG to compressed Video File with C#

Tags: c#, video, mjpeg

I'd like to convert a MJPEG Stream from an IP-Camera to a compressed Video File. To access the stream i use the MJPEF Decoder found here: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder. If i write the Frames to an avi File with an avifil32.dll Wrapper i need 100MB for 1 minute with 5 fps. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the AVI writers provided by [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/):

- `AForge.Video.VFW.AVIWriter` uses the Video for Windows API
- `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter` uses the FFMPEG library

The two important parameters for each are `FrameRate` and `BitRate`, experiment with those to get the quality/size trade-off you need.

FYI, AForge also includes a MJPEG client and a library for video motion detection.